# Snowflake SQL Filter by transactions in the last rolling 30 days

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a data table something similar to having a customer ID and an item purchase date as shown below. As a filter, I want to return customer ID IFF a given Customer ID has at least 1 purchase in the last 30 **rolling** days.

Is this something that can be done with a simple `WHERE` clause ? For my purposes, this data table has many records where a customer ID might have hundreds of transactions

```
Customer ID Item Date Purchased
233         2021-05-27
111         2021-05-27
111         2021-05-21
23          2021-05-12
412         2021-03-11 
111         2021-03-03
```

Desired output:

```
Customer ID
233
111
23
```

Originally thought to use a CTE to initially filter out any users that don't have at least 1 item purchase within the last 30 days. Tried the following two different where statements but both didn't work returning incorrect date timeframes.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM data d 
    WHERE 30 <= datediff(days, d.ITEM_PURCHASE_DATE, current_date) X
    WHERE t.DATE_CREATED <= current_date + interval '30 days' X
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get the customers that have made at least one purchase in the last 30 days you can do this:

```sql
select distinct
    customer_id
from sample_table
where item_date_purchased > dateadd(day, -30, current_date());
```

the [dateadd](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html) function shown above returns a date 30 days prior to the current date.

Answer (score 7):

The approach with `INTERVAL` was almost correct.

```
SELECT * 
FROM data d 
WHERE d.DATE_CREATED <= current_date + interval '30 days'  
                        -- this date is from the future instead of the past
```

=>

```
SELECT * 
FROM data d 
WHERE d.DATE_CREATED >= current_date - interval '30 days'
```